# How do you set the iPhone to play music/audio while asleep?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to set the iPhone to play music/audio while asleep? If so, how do you configure it?

EDIT:

I don't mean locking the phone or turning the screen off. When I play an audio file (for instance, http://m.insightforliving.ca/current-broadcast) and the phone goes to sleep (I think it's called deep sleep), the audio stops playing. Is there a way of setting it up in iPhone that the audio keeps playing even in deep sleep?

Comment: Do you mean something like starting music playback then turning the screen off or music starting automatically at some point or something else?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: By the way, there's nothing called "deep sleep" on iOS - there's only screen on, screen off, and shut down. Obviously, nothing runs when the device is shut down.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't able to duplicate this behavior. Are you using headphones, and playing it in iOS Safari? I did edit my answer, which may make it more helpful for you.

Comment: I'm playing it in iOS Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:
In this case it sounds like we want to disable auto-lock. This can be done by opening Settings.app, going to General, then scrolling down to "Auto-Lock". Set this to "Never".

---

It is possible use the speakers on iPhone to play even when the device is locked. This is possible by:

1. Opening Music.app
2. Select song/album/playlist
3. Lock the device. The music will continue to play.

You can also double tap the home button when the device is locked to show play/pause controls for the last-played music.

Also, other apps continue to play when the device is locked such as Voice Memos.

Note: all audio will shut off when the phone is **powered off**.

Comment: My Auto-Lock is set to 5 mins - it does not shut down the music when the iPhone locks

Answer (score 3):

I had what what I think is the same problem. The phone worked perfectly for years. i.e. It played music even when the screen was locked. Today it it stopped all audio when the screen locked itself. I rebooted it and the problem was solved.